# Set a PHP ini setting to sudo & bash a command?

Tags: php, bash

Ok so I am setting up sendmail within php.ini on a Ubuntu 14 server.

If I run from the command line (I am logged in as su-)

```
sudo sendmail -f myemail -X bash >(php myscript)
```

It works fine. So I have setup Visudo with:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And set my php.ini file with the following:

```
sendmail_path = "sudo sendmail -f myemail -X bash >(php myscript)"
```

But for some reason it won't work when I try and my basic mailing script:

```
<?php
// subject
$subject = 'sent with logging';

// message
$message = 'This time Ive turned on logging so lets see';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: me' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
$sent = mail('test address', $subject, $message, $headers);
echo $sent ? 1 : 0;
echo '<br>';
echo 'Mail sent at '.date('H:i:s');
?>
```

So how can you set a sudo based command to run and work from within php.ini?

Comment: If the `www-data` user can run `sudo` with no password, than any command injection vulnerability in your PHP deployment will allow an attacker to gain a full root shell on your machine. The reason the web server runs as its own user is to *limit* the harm that such an attack could do. Please reconsider your choices here.